# Understanding subsequence convergence for Neumann's Minimax theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, game-theory

Context: von Neumann proved that if $f$ is a continuous function on two compact sets $X,Y$ of the Generalized Euclideian Field, such that: $f$ is convex on $X$ and concave on $Y$ (vice versa also allowed and applies the same) then we have that
\begin{align}
\boxed{\max_{x \in X} \min_{y \in Y} f(x,y) = \max_{y \in Y} \min_{x \in X}f(x,y)}.
\end{align}

Basically what it says is that it outlines the necessary and able conditions for guaranteeing the equality part on the also very well known (from Multivariable Calculus) [Max-Min Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality).

My question starts now: I have been studying a part of this proof for a while now. The first parts are easy enough, since they start with the assumption that $f$ is already strictly-convex/strictly-concave.

However, what happens when $f$ is NOT strictly-convex/strictly-concave? The author says we take $\epsilon > 0$ and create
\begin{align}
f_{\epsilon} (x,y) = f(x,y) - \epsilon ||x||^2 + \epsilon ||y||^2
\end{align}
so that $f_{\epsilon}$ now can fulfill our original premise and therefore it can have a sagmatic/saddle point $(x_\epsilon, y_\epsilon) \in X \times Y $. We then take the compactness of $A \times B$ and setting $\epsilon_j \to 0$ we can find a subsequence $(x_{\epsilon_{j}}, y_{\epsilon_{j}} )$ that converges to a sagmatic/saddle point of $f$.

I am completely out of ideas. What I know is that another condition for sagmatic point is
\begin{align}
f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}, \exists (x_0 ,y_0): f(x, y_0) \leq f(x_0, y_0 ) \leq f(x_0, y).
\end{align}

How can we tie those together?

Many thanks!

Comment: these points are usually called ``saddle points''

Comment: To me it seems that the proof is: pass to the limit with $\epsilon\searrow0$ in the last inequality.

Comment: @daw good point

Comment: @daw how would you do it? can you please provide a sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon)$ be a saddle point of $f_\epsilon$. That is,
for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, we have
$$
f_\epsilon(x,y_\epsilon) \le 
f_\epsilon(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon) \le 
f_\epsilon(x_\epsilon,y) .
$$
Assume $(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon)\to (x_0,y_0)$, then we can pass to the limit in the above inequality for $\epsilon\searrow0$ and fixed $(x,y)$ to obtain
$$
f(x,y_0) \le 
f(x_0,y_0) \le 
f(x_0,y) .
$$
Here, we used that $X\times Y$ is compact hence bounded, and $f$ is continuous. Now this inequality is fulfilled for all $(x,y)$, and $(x_0,y_0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very elegant!